# Linkage Error with Apache CXF (JAXBAttachmentMarchaller) and JBOSS 5.2

Tags: java, maven, jboss, cxf, linkageerror

I have a Linkage error where it seems like Jboss (5.2) provides one version of the class `org.apache.cxf.jaxb.attachment.JAXBAttachmentMarchaller` whereas I somewhere provide another implementation of the class. I have searched for the class and it is the maven project `cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb` which contains it, so I've excluded that project from my dependency which use Apache CXF, but the error remains.

I don't really understand the error message, especially the part *...have different Class objects for the type shaller.addMtomAttachment(Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;*

- What is **shaller**? How can a method call of a variable be a type?
- How can do I find the dependency that is responsible for packaging `JAXBAttachmentMarchaller` into the project?

Please correct me if there is another solution to this problem.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method
"org.apache.cxf.jaxb.attachment.JAXBAttachmentMarshaller
        .addMtomAttachment(Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;Ljava/lang/String;
                           Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;" 
the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader)
of the current class, org/apache/cxf/jaxb/attachment/JAXBAttachmentMarshaller, 
and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for 
the type shaller.addMtomAttachment(Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; Ljava/lang/String;
                          Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; used in the signature
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBase.getAttachmentMarshaller(JAXBDataBase.java:82)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.createMarshaller(DataWriterImpl.java:127)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:169)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleHeaderPart(SoapOutInterceptor.java:242)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.writeSoapEnvelopeStart(SoapOutInterceptor.java:164)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:81)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:61)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy440.getDeviceDetails(Unknown Source)
at com.company.MyMethod(MyClass.java:52)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can do I find the dependency that is responsible for packaging JAXBAttachmentMarchaller into the project?

Search on the web of a maven project which bundles the file. For me it was `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws`.

What you need to do is to remove this dependency from the assembly, it must not be included in the WAR/EAR-file since JBoss provides another version of the dependency and there is a conflict.

Look in your `pom.xml` for `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws` and make sure it has the tag `<scope>provided</scope>` since we want the server to provide the dependency. If you don't have `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws` in your `pom.xml` it means that the project is a sub dependency to one of your dependencies. This is tricky to resolve, since the dependency can exist in several sub dependencies. Some people recommend to use `mvn dependency:tree` in order to find which projects that are responsible for bundling the dependency in the WAR/EAR-file.

I found the responsible project, which was an in house component, so I could easily add `<scope>provided</scope>` to the component to remove `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws*jar` from the WAR/EAR-file. I verified that the dependency was no longer bundled in the WAR-file by extracting it and listing `WEB-INF/lib` where it was no longer listed.

If you cannot change the scope, you have must use the exclude-tag to remove it from the assembly.